# Python NetworkX edge lists out of range

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx

I'm currently working with NetworkX in Python2 and just faced a weird situation here. I wanted to discover what nodes are connected to each node in a graph, so I wrote this for loop. (I know that each node is only connected to two other nodes, but I need the exact labels)

```
    for i in sorted(graph.nodes(), key=int):
        b = [int(edge_tuple[0]) for edge_tuple in PedigNetwork.in_edges(i)]
        print i, b
```

So, for every element `i`, `b` is a list of length 2, containing the identification of the two nodes that connect to node `i`.

But when I try to access the FIRST (`b[0]`) element of that list, it returns an error pointing that the index is out of range.

```
    print i, b[0]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

But if the list has two elements, `[0]` is clearly not out of range.

Any ideia how could I solve it?
Am I missing something really basic here?

I want to access the first and second elements individually and store them into lists after that.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `G.predecessors(i)` will give all nodes that have edges pointing towards `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error implies `b` is the empty list, `[]`:

```
In [143]: b = []

In [147]: b[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

That could happen if there is a node `i` for which `PedigNetwork.in_edges(i)`
returns an empty list. To test this theory, you could run

```
for i in sorted(graph.nodes(), key=int):
    b = [int(edge_tuple[0]) for edge_tuple in PedigNetwork.in_edges(i)]
    if not b:
        print('Empty list: {}, {}'.format(i, b))
        break
```

If it prints `Empty list: ...` then you have your culprit.

---

If you wish to skip nodes where `PedigNetwork.in_edges(i)` is empty, you could use

```
for i in sorted(graph.nodes(), key=int):
    b = [int(edge_tuple[0]) for edge_tuple in PedigNetwork.in_edges(i)]
    if len(b) < 2: continue
    print(i, b[0], b[1])
```

or

```
for i in sorted(graph.nodes(), key=int):
    b = [int(edge_tuple[0]) for edge_tuple in PedigNetwork.in_edges(i)]
    if len(b) >= 2:
        print(i, b[0], b[1])
```

The advantage of using the first option, `if len(b) < 2: continue` is that it saves
you one level of indentation.

Comment: That's exactly it, there are nodes which have no edges. In that case, should I test if b is empty before trying to obtain the subset?